# Rails Administrate - Sort BelongsTo column in Collection alphabetically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-administrate, administrate

I need some help, as I've spent the past couple of days digging through the repo's issues / PRs figuring out how to order a resource's belongs_to association alphabetically in its collection.
Using Rails `5.0.7` and Administrate `0.10.0`.

In my situation, I have a Dish model and a Restaurant model. Dish belongs to Restaurant and Restaurant has many dishes.
I noticed that when one clicks the `<th>` for Restaurant, it orders the column based on the restaurant's `id` and not the restaurant's `name`. I want to change it so that, it orders the column based on the restaurant's name and alphabetically. Relevant code below.

`dish_dashboard.rb`

```
class DishDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    diets: Field::HasMany,
    restaurant: Field::BelongsTo.with_options(
      searchable: true,
      searchable_field: 'name'
    ),
    id: Field::Number,
    name: Field::String,
    description: Field::Text,
    picture: Administrate::Field::Image,
    price: Field::PriceField,
    price_currency: Field::String,
    deleted_at: Field::DateTime,
    published_at: Field::DateTime,
    created_at: Field::DateTime,
    featured: Field::Boolean
  }.freeze

  COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES = [
    :name,
    :restaurant,
    :diets,
    :picture,
    :created_at,
    :featured,
  ].freeze
  ...
end
```

Dishes' `_collection.html.haml`

```
%table.collection-data{"aria-labelledby" => "page-title"}
  %thead
    %tr
      - collection_presenter.attribute_types.each do |attr_name, attr_type|
        %th{class: "cell-label cell-label--#{attr_type.html_class} cell-label--#{collection_presenter.ordered_html_class(attr_name)}", scope: "col", role: "columnheader", :'aria-sort' => "#{sort_order(collection_presenter.ordered_html_class(attr_name))}"}
          = link_to(sanitized_order_params.merge(collection_presenter.order_params_for(attr_name))) do
            = attr_name.to_s.titleize
            - if collection_presenter.ordered_by?(attr_name)
              %span{class: "cell-label__sort-indicator cell-label__sort-indicator--#{collection_presenter.ordered_html_class(attr_name)}"}
                &#9660;
      %th{:class => "cell-label"} ACTIONS
  %tbody
    - resources.each do |resource|
      %tr.js-table-row{tabindex: 0, :'role' => 'link', data: {url: "#{polymorphic_path([namespace, resource])}"}}
        - collection_presenter.attributes_for(resource).each do |attribute|
          - next if attribute.html_class === 'boolean'
          %td{class: "cell-data cell-data--#{attribute.html_class}"}
            = link_to polymorphic_path([namespace, resource]), class: 'action-show' do
              = render_field attribute
        - if current_page?(admin_dishes_path)
          - if resource.featured?
            %td
              = button_tag '', class: 'btn toggle-actvation-btn unfeature-btn', type: 'button', data: { 'id': resource.id }
          - else
            %td
              = button_tag '', class: 'btn toggle-actvation-btn feature-btn', type: 'button', data: { 'id': resource.id }
          %td
            = button_to 'Delete', admin_dish_path(resource.id), method: 'delete', class: 'delete-btn'`enter code here`
```

Right now, it appears like so. [collection's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73U8d.png)

I've tried using the order option, but according to the docs, it's only for dropdown menu, not for a table, unfortunately.
Is there a way to let the column be ordered alphabetically based on its name or I'll have to do it manually?

Comment: Could you post some codes? It's difficult to visualize your table without seeing your codebase.

Comment: I've added some code above. I believe those are relevant to my question. @Emu

Comment: Does the example in [this PR](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/pull/1104) not work?

Comment: @MarkMerritt Nope, it does not work. I even tried `scope: -> { Dish.order(restaurant: :desc) }` and it still doesn't order the table from the highest id to the smallest id, so it seems that `scope` is useless.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692607/how-to-sort-records-by-published-at/70392233#70392233