# Rails Administrate gem: How to sort records by 'Published At'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administrate

I'm very much new to the [Administrate gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) for Ruby on Rails.
I can't make it sort/order posts by "Published At". Records seem to be ordered by their id's and not the `published_at` date, how can I make it work?

See the example app over at Heroku:
https://administrate-prototype.herokuapp.com/admin/blog/posts

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick note: Administrate is not by Heroku. It just happens that the demo app is on Heroku. I have edited your question to correctly reflect this.

Comment: I'm looking at the demo app and I can't see what you mean. If I click "Published At", it does order by this column. Can you elaborate as to what you see? Providing screenshots could be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looking for `Model.order` function, here are the docs:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Answer (score 1):

If you have a model named `Post`, when defining it in the controller function `show` or any other that you are using, you can get the record like below so that it comes sorted by published_at

```
Post.order(published_at: :desc) # ActiveRecord ordering
# OR
Post.sort_by(&:published_at) # pure Ruby sorting implementation
```

If you always want it come in sorted by published_at you can use default_scope of rails in `Post` like below -

```
default_scope { order(published_at: :desc) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its easy, you need to modify the `request.query_parameters` not `params` to get your job done.

---

#### Here is an example

```rb
# app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Admin
  class UsersController < Admin::ApplicationController
    before_action :default_params

    def default_params
      request.query_parameters[:user]             ||= {}    # change :user --> your resource
      request.query_parameters[:user][:order]     ||= :id   # your field
      request.query_parameters[:user][:direction] ||= :desc # your direction
    end
```